# Convert byte array to integer with lower and upper bound

Tags: c#, performance, math, random

I have a method that pseudo-randomly encrypts a byte array. I would like to convert the encrypted byte-array to a C# int (4 bytes), while observing a user-specified lower and upper bound (e.g. give me a number between 1 and 10)

What is the most secure and performant way of achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean by the upper and lower bound?

Comment: @SohaibJundi see edit

Comment: What do you mean "secure"? Also there is absolutely no way to *encrypt* 4 bytes into range smaller then full `int` (32 bits). (If you figured out how to achieve encryption that consistently and reversibly can map values to smaller range... either share whatever you are drinking or collect your billions)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am not asking to encrypt 4 bytes in a range smaller than "full" int. What is a full int anyway? Secure in the sense that it cannot be gamed to predict numeric values

Comment: You are not looking for `new Random().Next(1,10)` are you? Please [edit] post and clarify what you are looking for (feel free to move "encryption" context down to some sort of extended details section). Also you may want to clarify whether or not you are looking to compute some sort of hash of those values... Some example input/output would be welcome.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. If you encrypt and then "convert" 4 bytes to an int between 1 and 10 you are throwing away (a lot of) information and will be unable to decrypt.

Comment: @JamesKPolk not looking to decrypt. The user can specify any range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (C# int32 range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `System.ByteConverter.ToInt32(arr, start_index)`.

From your description of the array, the start index would likely be zero.

I am not sure what you mean by upper and lower bound, but if you mean you want a random number, you could use a variety of functions to get a value in between the two numbers. If you have semi-uniform distribution, the modulus function would work nicely. In that case, your random number would simply be `lowerBound + (System.ByteConverter.ToInt32(arr, start_index) % (upperBound - lowerBound))`.